# Combinar checkbox y dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, dropdownlist, table

Me gustaría crear una modificación de esta tabla y código JS:

**HTML**

```
<div class="column left">
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Occupation</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Race</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr gender="male" race="sith">
            <td>Darth Vader</td>
            <td>Dark Lord of the Sith</td>
            <td>Male</td>
            <td>Sith</td>
        </tr>
        <tr gender="male" race="human">
            <td>Boba Fett</td>
            <td>Bounty Hunter</td>
            <td>Male</td>
            <td>Human</td>      
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div class="column right">
<div><b>Filters</b></div>
<div><b>Gender</b></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="male">Male</input></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="non-binary">Non-Binary</input></div>
```

**JS**

```
var tableRows = $('.column.left tbody tr'),
        filterBoxes = $('.column.right :checkbox').on('change', filterTable);

    function filterTable() {
      var filter_selector = '';
      $('.column.right :checked').each(function() {
        filter_selector += '[' + $(this).attr('name') + '=' + '"' + $(this).val() + '"]';
      });
      if (filter_selector.length < 1) {
        tableRows.show();
      } else {
        tableRows.hide().filter(filter_selector).show();
      }
    }
```

Me gustaría poder añadir un dropdown y que, junto a los checkboxes, el usuario pueda filtrar según lo que desee. Se debería poder elegir checkboxes y dropwdown (únicamente 1) como filtros.

Comment: Cuál es el error?

Comment: ¿Puedes ser más específico en lo que quieres?

Comment: Sí, disculpad. Me gustaría que el código JS también leyera un dropwdown. Así solo lee los checkboxes. Me gustaría añadir un drowdown y que, junto a los checkboxes, se filtrara la tabla según elección.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agregue un select y modifique la función, para que ante el cambio del mismo, se agregue el valor correspondiente al selector. Te dejo el [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7nm5kd06/)